# How can I backup a mount without a corresponding /dev special file?

Tags: backup, devices, block-device

Typically, I would just e.g. `dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > backup.gz` or something similar, but in this embedded device, I have a filesystem

```
/dev/root on /rom type squashfs (ro,relatime)
```

**without** a corresponding `/dev/root` special file. I suspect it's deleted by a startup script.

Is there a way to find the major/minor version numbers of the mount and then manually create the `/dev` entry using `mknod`?

Or alternatively, is there some other way to access the raw block device so I can copy it?

Comment: Too few info but as you write that device is created by a startup script, then if you clone the "disk" you also clone the startup script, don't you? But `dd` of a device with mounted filesystems is not good idea.

Comment: As far as I can see, the major/minor of a mounted squashfs _file_ can be found using `findmnt` or `/proc/self/mountinfo` (one of `findmnt` sources). Not sure whether they are available on your system, though, nor if the resulting block device will work there.

Comment: Fwiw this was an openwrt system, and the mounts were listed under `/etc/mtd` with corresponding device nodes in `/dev`. But this doesn't answer the general question.